# How to include double quotes in select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

i have a table like

```
 id    name 
 10    bob
 20    bill
```

i want to select only name column in output with double quotes

like `select '"'||name||'"' from table`
 it is giving me the correct output but is there any other way without using concatenation ...

Thank you..

Comment: don't think so. If you don't like the syntax, some dbms' do support some kind of concat() function, so you can write it as concat('"', name, '"')

Answer (score 9):

Using this you can get result with double quotes

> ' " ' + columnName + ' " '

Example

#### Query

```
SELECT '"'+Name+'"' , Age
FROM customer
```

#### Result

> "Viranja" | 27

Answer (score 3):

Create a virtual column that adds the quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE
....
quoted_name VARCHAR2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('"' || name || '"') VIRTUAL,
...
```

See here for more information:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1.php

Answer (score 0):

this will check for any name with at least one double quote

```
select * from table
where name like '%"%'
```

Comment: OP doesn't *search* for quotes, just wants to output around name.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to be able to "export" the result into space or comma-delimited text file, use a view to "format" your data. You will need to this for your date columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios you would want to use double quotes in sql in my opinion.

1. Updating a string column which contains single multiple quotes in it. (you have to escape it)
2. updating blog contents in columns which you cant edit in "edit top 200 rows"

   so, if you want to use double quotes follow this.

   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
       BEGIN
       DECLARE @YourSqlStmt AS VarChar(5000) -- Declare a variable.
       SET @YourSqlStmt = "ok"
       PRINT @YourSqlStmt -- do your operations here
       END

   This saves time and you need not to escape single quotes in a existing string content of the column.